# Magento routing child

Tags: magento

I created my own extenstion which is portfolio, here is config for frontend:

```
 <frontend>
        <routers>
            <portfolio>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>xxx_Portfolio</module>
                    <frontName>portfolio</frontName>
                </args>
            </portfolio>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <portfolio>
                    <file>portfolio.xml</file>
                </portfolio>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
```

so it is fired up on url base/portfolio
but I would like to create route for every project in portfolio, so url will be:
base/portfolio/project1
base/portfolio/project2

how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this using below sample code

```
class Namespace_Portfolio_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
   public function indexAction ()
   {
     echo 'test index';// its your working code that you access from [base-url]/portfolio
   }
 }
```

for first project(controller) in your case create new file in controllers folder

```
[magento]\app\code\[codepool]\[Namespace]\[Portfolio]\controllers\Project1Controller.php



class Namespace_Portfolio_Project1Controller extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {
       public function indexAction ()
       {
         echo 'welcome to project1';// its your working code that you access from [base-url]/portfolio
       }
     }
```

same for project2 `[magento]\app\code\[codepool]\[Namespace]\[Portfolio]\controllers\Project2Controller.php`

```
class Namespace_Portfolio_Project2Controller extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {
       public function indexAction ()
       {
         echo 'welcome to project2';// its your working code that you access from [base-url]/portfolio
       }
     }
```

hope this help you.

**Note: my suggestion is instead of create new controller for your requirement use same controller action & use [url-rewrite](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-url-rewrites). it will help you to achieve same that you want.**